# how to cut a string every n characters? but it only cuts when there are spaces

Tags: java

I am trying to cut a long string into lines of that string, the length of the lines is decided by the function. The function will not cut the words in the middle.

I have attempted many ways to do so using substrings and such but I am not that great at string manipulation. I have found a similar issue online, but it was in JavaScript and some of the code I could not fully translate to Java (maybe because i'm inexperienced with it...)

```
public static List<String> descriptionFormatter(String string, int amt)
{
    String[] splitted = string.split(" ");
    String part = "";
    List<String> finalDesc = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < splitted.length; i++)
    {
        part = part + " " + splitted[i];
        if(part.length() >= amt)
        {
            finalDesc.add(part);
            part = "";
        }

    }
    return finalDesc;
}
```

e.g.
I have a string "hello world apple orange grapes juice spagehtti sauce milk"
and I want to cut it every 34 characters (considering all the requirements above)
so I call

```
descriptionFormatter(string, 34);
```

wanted result a string array/list:

1. hello world apple orange grapes juice
2. spagehtti sauce milk

actual result:

1. hello world apple orange grapes juice

I have gotten as far as almost getting it to work, but it sometimes it skips the remaining words at the end and puts spaces before the first word. How do I make it function as I intend it to?

Comment: check if current length + next length is > target if so dont add to current bucket add it to next and increment current bucket

Comment: You'll probably want to use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try traversing the input `string` with two indexes say `beginIndex` and `endIndex` and take `substrings` from the input `string` as you go:

```
public static List<String> descriptionFormatter(String str, int amt) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // trim the input string to avoid empty strings at the end
    str = str.trim();

    int beginIndex = 0;  
    int endIndex = amt; 

    final int length = str.length();
    while(endIndex < length) {
        // if we landed on something other than space
        // increase the end index for the substring
        // until we hit a space
        while(endIndex < length && str.charAt(endIndex) != ' ') {
            ++endIndex;
        }
        result.add(str.substring(beginIndex, endIndex).trim());

        beginIndex = endIndex;
        endIndex += amt;
    }
    // Add the last string if any left
    if(beginIndex < length) {
        result.add(str.substring(beginIndex).trim());
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "hello world apple orange grapes juice spagehtti sauce milk";
    descriptionFormatter(str, 34).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
hello world apple orange grapes juice
spagehtti sauce milk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```java
static List<String> split(String s, int size) { 
  return split(s.toCharArray(), size);
}

static List<String> split(char[] s, int size) {
  List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    if (i % size == 0) {
      if(s[i] == ' ') {
        strs.add(sb.toString());
        sb = new StringBuilder();
      }else {
        StringBuilder newStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int length = sb.length();
        while (length > 0 && sb.charAt(length - 1) != ' ') {
          newStringBuilder.insert(0, sb.charAt(length -  1));
          sb.deleteCharAt(length - 1);
          --length;
        }
        if(sb.length() > 0) strs.add(sb.toString());
        sb = newStringBuilder;
      }
    }
    sb.append(s[i]);
  }
  if (sb.length() > 0) {
    strs.add(sb.toString());
  }
  return strs;
}
```

Comment: It cuts the word "juice" in the middle

1. hello world apple orange grapes ju
2. ice spagehtti sauce milk

Comment: now it rolls back until it finds the first space so that it does not cut the word `juice`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static List<String> descriptionFormatter(String string, int amt) {
        List<String> stringPieces = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder strOfMaxLen = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder strExceedsMaxLen = new StringBuilder();
        String[] splitted = string.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0 ; i < splitted.length; i++) {

            String piece = splitted[i];
            int pieceLen = piece.length();

            if (strOfMaxLen.length()+pieceLen < amt) {
                if (strOfMaxLen.length() != 0) {
                    strOfMaxLen.append(" ");
                }
                strOfMaxLen.append(piece);
            } else {
                if (strExceedsMaxLen.length() != 0) {
                    strExceedsMaxLen.append(" ");
                }
                strExceedsMaxLen.append(piece);
            }
        }
        stringPieces.add(strOfMaxLen.toString());
        stringPieces.add(strExceedsMaxLen.toString());

        return stringPieces;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

and yet another :)

```
private static List<String> descriptionFormatter(String string, int amt){
    String[] splitted = string.split(" ");
    List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : splitted) {
        if (sb.length() + s.length() > amt) {
            ans.add(sb.toString()); // end the line add to list
            sb.setLength(0); //clear the current string
        } else {
            if (sb.length()!=0)
                sb.append(" "); // if it's the first don't add a space
            sb.append(s); // add the word
        }
    }
    ans.add(sb.toString());// add the last line
    return ans;
}
```